# What am I doing wrong with order()?

Tags: dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe:

|  | p.value | gene |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0.302436613525335 | UBE2Q2P2;100134869 |
| 3 | 0.15026618422578 | SDR16C6P;442388 |
| 4 | 0.747366468058889 | GTPBP6;8225 |
| 5 | 0.694564330199746 | EFCAB12;90288 |

I want to order it by `p.value` descendingly. I ran the code
`df<-df[order(-p.value),]` and got error message `Error in order(p.value) : object 'p.value' not found`

When I tried doing that for mtcars with column 'mpg' it did work. I just changed the variables' names, so I really am perplexed.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

```
df <-
  structure(list(p.value = c(0.302436613525335, 0.15026618422578, 
                             0.747366468058889, 0.694564330199746),
                 gene = c("UBE2Q2P2;100134869", 
                          "SDR16C6P;442388", "GTPBP6;8225", "EFCAB12;90288")),
            row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

You have to use `df$` to access `p.value`

```
df[order(-df$p.value),]
```

A `dplyr` alternative

```
dplyr::arrange(df, -p.value)
```